# Wordpress Website is being redirected to another link

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

I created a website on WordPress on the domain "https://new.fulldigitalnews.com/" and then I uploaded the files and database to another domain "https://bsengworks.com/" and also I put the URL correctly in the database.

But still when I open "https://bsengworks.com/" it is redirected to the previous domain "https://new.fulldigitalnews.com/"

Help me with it.

[database wp_option SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q2cf.png)
even user URL is correct.

Tried removing the wordpress installation from Cpanel. And I re-installed it and created again but it is being redirected again.

Comment: I think you should change `URL` in `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to configure the DNS setting. I have never used WordPress as a host but have used other hosts and tried doing similar stuff eventually, I just contacted the host support, and they walked me through changing a bunch of DNS values. Not sure of your exact situation with WordPress, but I would just contact them and see if they can help.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change links in database `wp_options` table in two rows. First row contains `option_name`="home" and other `option_name`="siteurl" and change link in both rows then it works.

[image: image of wp_options rows]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't redirect for me.

Have you tried it in a different/private browser?

It's possible the old URL is cached in your browser and it's sending you to it incorrectly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).